# How to Access private parameterized method of private inner class with in a static class in JAVA

Tags: java, reflection, inner-classes

How can I access getMeSomething method of Inner class from the main method? All I need is to be able to send an integer and get the returned value in main method.

```
public class OuterClass {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Using Java Reflection...I tried to create an inner class Object
    //created a outer class object
    //and invoke the method without any success
   }

  static class Inner {
     private class Private {
        private int getMeSomething(int num) {
            return (num*2);
        }
     }
  }//end of inner class
} //end of outer class
```

Comment: Well you need an instance of `Inner.Private` given that it's an instance method...

Comment: Or make `Private` and `Private.getMeSomething()` static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need both an instance of Inner and of Private:

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Using Java Reflection...I tried to create an inner class Object
        //created a outer class object
        //and invoke the method without any success
               Private p = new Inner ().new Private ();
           System.out.println(""+p.getMeSomething(21));
       }
```

Comment: your answer works...but...my requirement also needs an **Object o** to be created and used to hold the reference of the instance of the class OuterClass.Inner.Private. Any tips?? Sorry for unclear question.